# Delete Version history

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-online, office-365, 2016, version-history

Is it possible to delete **Particular version history** using pnp or J-query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could delete version history by PowerShell script in SharePoint online. For more detailed information, refer to the article below.

[SharePoint Online: Delete Version History using PowerShell CSOM.](http://www.sharepointdiary.com/2016/02/sharepoint-online-delete-version-history-using-powershell.html)

In PnP PowerShell commands, there is no such PnP PowerShell command to delete the version history.

To use jQuery, you could get the specific version history by REST API, and then delete it. For more detailed information, refer to the post below.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/22bc1a22-d958-49d7-81a3-6009c39d88ac/delete-previous-versions-from-a-document-library-using-javascriptrest?forum=sharepointdevelopment